# Uninstalling ExpressJS 3.5.2 still leaves some kind of pointer

Tags: node.js, bash, express, osx-mavericks

When I uninstall ExpressJS using this command on OSX:

sudo npm uninstall express -g

it says it uninstalls but it leaves some kind of pointer that says this:

-bash: /usr/local/bin/express: No such file or directory

when I type in express.  Can you help me fix this?

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain this is normal. Bash is complaining that the express binary doesn't exist, which is true because you just uninstalled it. It's trying to search for the command you typed in /usr/local/bin/ because that's where it looks for all executable files (it's listed in your $PATH shell variable.) If you try to run `safasdfasdf` on the command line, it'll probably say `-bash: /usr/local/bin/safasdfasdf: No such file or directory`

Comment: No, it doesn't look like it:

-bash: fdfasf: command not found

This is more of an annoyance since I'm upgrade to Express 4.1

Answer (score 0):

So bash caches the full path of the command.  To clear it out, type this command:

hash -d express

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables